# warning 1292 when I use like in python with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql-like

I have to check if there is any null in my database,
and I need to check 11 columns (by `or`) and plus and like year (ex. `2017%`).

```
def test():
    sql= "select date from a000760 where (total_assets is null or total_liabilities is null or sales_figures is null or sales_cost is null or business_profits is null or gross_margin is null or current_income is null or depreciation_expense_of_tangible_assets is null or liquid_asset is null or noncurrent_asset is null or liquid_liability is null) and (date like '2010%')"
    curs.execute(sql)
    #year="2010"
    #curs.execute("select date from a000760 where (total_assets is null or total_liabilities is null or sales_figures is null or sales_cost is null or business_profits is null or gross_margin is null or current_income is null or depreciation_expense_of_tangible_assets is null or liquid_asset is null or noncurrent_asset is null or liquid_liability is null) and (date like %s)",year)
    result = curs.fetchall()
    if len(result)>0: // print shows () even if it's none. so, I use this
        print "a000760"
        print "2010 null exists"
```

It's the test version of one table.
I have to check more than 2000 tables.
It works for this def and shows error (only for one table).
But it doesn't work for total tables.
And I get this error:

```
Warning: (1292, "Incorrect date value: '2010%' for column 'date' at row 1")
```

I don't know how...
I've searched for the whole grammar,
but when I type `%2017%` it doesn't work.

Comment: All the other questions where this error happens are when they're trying to insert an invalid date into the table. I don't get this error when I try to compare a date in a `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `like` with dates!  Dates are not strings.

You can just do:

```
year(date) = 2010
```

Or:

```
date >= '2010-01-01' and date < '2011-01-01'
```